# Confused on the notation from a TI datasheet

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, texas-instruments, powermosfet, equation

So I'm trying to implement this IC onto a controller that I'm designing: https://www.ti.com/product/UCC5350 I understand for the most part how to apply it, I am just lost on one key part

[image: this is equation 1 on the datasheet for this IC]

The specific point on concern that I have is the double vertical lines. I've never seen this notation and not sure what it's supposed to represent. Does anyone know what it is?

Thanks

Comment: I think the double vertical bars mean "in parallel". Cheers.

Comment: Notation R1||R2 indicates that the resistors R1 and R2 are in parallel: https://www.google.com/search?q=symbol+of+two+resistors+in+parallel&oq=symbol+of+two+resistors+in+parallel&aqs=chrome..69i57.11479j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

It is two resistance in parallel. Summary (Rnmos*Roh)/(Rnmos+Roh). Document has an example of calculation.

Answer (score 2):

So after taking your suggestions, I tried doing Rnmos and Roh in parallel, and the rest in series, and it fits the examples given. Thanks guys!

Comment: How nice to hear your good news. Have a great locking down day. Cheers.